# Node error " Cannot read property 'insertId' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new in node and I download an signup example it is show an error:

> " Cannot read property 'insertId' of undefined"

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});


passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM singup WHERE id = ? ",[id], function(err, rows){
        done(err, rows[0]);
    });
});


passport.use(
    'local-signup',
    new LocalStrategy({

        fullnameField : 'fullname',
        usernameField : 'username',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true 
    },
    function(req,fullname, username, password, done) {

        connection.query("SELECT * FROM singup WHERE username = ?",[username], function(err, rows) {
            if (err)
                return done(err);
            if (rows.length) {
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That username is already taken.'));
            } 
            else {

                var newUserMysql = {
                    id:"2",
                    fullname: fullname,
                    username: username,
                    password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, null, null)  
                };

                var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO singup (fullname, username, password ) values (?,?,?)";

                connection.query(insertQuery,[newUserMysql.fullname, newUserMysql.username, newUserMysql.password],function(err, rows) {

                    newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;
                    return done(null, newUserMysql);
                });
            }
        });
    })
);
```

```
 //TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertId' of undefined
    at Query.<anonymous> (E:\testing\nodejs\config\passport.js:71:48)
    at Query.<anonymous> (E:\testing\nodejs\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
    at Query._callback (E:\testing\nodejs\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:468:16)
    at Query.Sequence.end (E:\testing\nodejs\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (E:\testing\nodejs\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:90:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (E:\testing\nodejs\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:278:23)
    at Parser.write (E:\testing\nodejs\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (E:\testing\nodejs\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\testing\nodejs\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:91:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\testing\nodejs\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:502:10)
```

Comment: You'll probably want to `console.log(err)` before assuming `rows` is successful.

Comment: there is no any data in callback function. there seems to be error

Answer (score 3):

First, always check for errors!
If there is an error, the rows field will be undefined. (**Which seem to be the case**)

If there is no error, then log the rows field to see it's structure.

The rows field might be an array, so in order to access the insertId, you could try changing

From

```
newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId
```

To

```
newUserMysql.id = rows[0].insertId
```